# FB Graph API : FB posts (in public status) are not showned to Fan users

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created my first app on Facebook Developper in order to use it with Facebook Graph API and automatically publish on my FB page.

With an admin fb account, no problem i see all posts of the page.
With others FB accounts who simply liked the page, posts automaticaly published by the app (in public status are not showned to users. They only see posts published manually by a FB page admin.

FB APP is in developper mode.
After starting a FB advertising for my page, I see posts with a fan FB account.
I understand nothing!

So I have two questions:

- FB APP should be in "live" mode so that Fan page users can see posts automatically published?
- Do ou think can FB ads impact the operation and make visible the posts to fans?
  Thanks a lot.
  Théo.

Comment: Yes, your app needs to be in live mode, before any content created through it will become visible for the general public.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe